# Writeln to stream

Tags: delphi, stream

Does somebody know how to associate a file(text) descriptor with a TStream component, so that writeln() like I/O can be redirected to the stream ? (like the FPC unit StreamIO). Is there a predefined function somewhere (I'm using XE, but it would be nice if it also worked on 2009)

I've a lot of business code that relies on the writeln(f,) like formatting options that I would like to update to log over the network. This upgrade must be done in a relative safe way, since the files must remain the same to the byte.

(Rewriting this business code using other means is not really an option, if it does not exists I'll have to try myself, or will have to do with a writing to a tempfile and reading it back)

Added: any example of custom textrecs would be welcome and/or which of it fields have safe room for user state.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Peter Below wrote such a beast for Delphi too, also called StreamIO, see http://groups.google.com/group/borland.public.delphi.objectpascal/msg/d682a8b5a5760ac4?pli=1

(linked post contains the unit).

Comment: +1 nice catch. I guess the FPC unit StreamIO is mostly the same... But I'm not sure it will handle Unicode text. You'll probably be stucked with Ansi kind of text when using Writeln(). And do not forget to set {$I-} for much faster process, if you are sure that your destination TStream won't fail.

Comment: Same unit name, same function name, we'll take this, thank you very much :-)

Comment: What problem do you have? The code is well commented and there is only one public procedure - `AssignStream`.

Comment: Call [Rewrite](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Standard_Routines_and_Input-Output) after `AssingStream` to open the file.

Comment: Sorry, becasue code is not formated. After execute code below STREAM.txt file is empty !? CODE:  procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  T: TextFile;
  S: TFileStream;
begin
  S := TFileStream.Create('D:\TMP\STREAM.txt', fmCreate);
  try
    AssignStream(T, S);
    Rewrite(T);
    WriteLn(T, 'abc', 123);
    WriteLn(T, 123, 'abc');
    CloseFile(T);
  finally
    S.Free;
  end;
end;

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at our [`SynCrtSock` Open Source unit](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynCrtSock.pas).

It implements a lot of features (including a http.sys based HTTP/1.1 server), but it has also some virtual text files to write into a socket. It is used e.g. to implement a HTTP client or server, or SMTP (to send an email).

It will be a good sample of how to create a "virtual" `TTextRec`, including reading & writing content, and also handling errors. The internal buffer size is also enhanced from its default value - here you have 1KB of caching by default, instead of 128 bytes.

For instance, here is how it can be used to send an email using SMTP (source code extracted from the unit):

```
function SendEmail(const Server: AnsiString; const From, CSVDest, Subject, Text: TSockData;
  const Headers: TSockData=''; const User: TSockData=''; const Pass: TSockData='';
  const Port: AnsiString='25'): boolean;
var TCP: TCrtSocket;
procedure Expect(const Answer: TSockData);
var Res: TSockData;
begin
  repeat
    readln(TCP.SockIn^,Res);
  until (Length(Res)<4)or(Res[4]<>'-');
  if not IdemPChar(pointer(Res),pointer(Answer)) then
    raise Exception.Create(string(Res));
end;
procedure Exec(const Command, Answer: TSockData);
begin
  writeln(TCP.SockOut^,Command);
  Expect(Answer)
end;
var P: PAnsiChar;
    rec, ToList: TSockData;
begin
  result := false;
  P := pointer(CSVDest);
  if P=nil then exit;
  TCP := Open(Server, Port);
  if TCP<>nil then
  try
    TCP.CreateSockIn; // we use SockIn and SockOut here
    TCP.CreateSockOut;
    Expect('220');
    if (User<>'') and (Pass<>'') then begin
      Exec('EHLO '+Server,'25');
      Exec('AUTH LOGIN','334');
      Exec(Base64Encode(User),'334');
      Exec(Base64Encode(Pass),'235');
    end else
      Exec('HELO '+Server,'25');
    writeln(TCP.SockOut^,'MAIL FROM:<',From,'>'); Expect('250');
    ToList := 'To: ';
    repeat
      rec := trim(GetNextItem(P));
      if rec='' then continue;
      if pos(TSockData('<'),rec)=0 then
        rec := '<'+rec+'>';
      Exec('RCPT TO:'+rec,'25');
      ToList := ToList+rec+', ';
    until P=nil;
    Exec('DATA','354');
    writeln(TCP.SockOut^,'Subject: ',Subject,#13#10,
      ToList,#13#10'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1'#13#10+
      'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'#13#10,
      Headers,#13#10#13#10,Text);
    Exec('.','25');
    writeln(TCP.SockOut^,'QUIT');
    result := true;
  finally
    TCP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

It will produce only *Ansi* content, by definition.

It targets Delphi 5 up to XE2 - so will include Delphi 2009 or XE.

Comment: +1 Also nice because it shows the other functions. Doesn't look 64-bit safe though. On *nix handle is 32-bit, and a pointer doesn't fit into it.

Comment: Hmm, on second checking, Delphi defines it as THandle. A windows type, and I don't know how they define that on *nix.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this in answer to another question, and it happens to be an approach worth considering although you want to do WriteLn(F,any,number,of,parameters), and I can not unfortunately exactly imitate `WriteLn(F, ...)`, with my `WriteLine(aString)` method.

1. I want to use ReadLn and WriteLn, but on streams.  Unfortunately I can't support arbitrary parameters in WriteLn, but I can write a string, which in combination with Format() is enough for me. ie `object.WriteLine( Format('stuff %d',[aIntValue]))`
2. I want to be able to read any file that might have CR, CR+LF, or just LF endings. I want only Ansi/Ascii support, as it is currently using RawByteString however, you can easily add UTF8 support to this class.
3. A modern Stream-like Class equivalent to TextFile (file of lines of text) is needed.  I call it `TTextFile`, and it's a reader/writer class wrapping a `Stream`.
4. It should work on 64 bit file position basis for files > 2 gb.
5. I want this to work in Delphi 7, and also in Delphi XE2, and everything in between.
6. I wanted it to be very very very fast.

--

To do a modern WriteLn on a file stream,  you would do this:

```
  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
    ts:TTextStream;
    begin
     ts := TTextStream.Create('c:\temp\test.txt', fm_OpenWriteShared);
     try
     for t := 1 to 1000 do 
       ts.WriteLine('something');
     end;
     finally
        ts.Free;
     end;
    end;
```

Here is what you would write if you want to test reading:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
ts:TTextStream;
s:String;
begin
 ts := TTextStream.Create('c:\temp\test.txt', fm_OpenReadShared);
 try
 while not ts.Eof do begin
   s := ts.ReadLine;
   doSomethingWith(s);
 end;
 finally
    ts.Free;
 end;
end;
```

The class is here:

```
unit textStreamUnit;
{$M+}


{$R-}

{
  textStreamUnit

  This code is based on some of the content of the JvCsvDataSet written by Warren Postma, and others,
  licensed under MOZILLA Public License.
 }

interface

uses
  Windows,
  Classes,
  SysUtils;


const
  cQuote = #34;
  cLf    = #10;
  cCR    = #13;

 { File stream mode flags used in TTextStream }

  { Significant 16 bits are reserved for standard file stream mode bits. }
  { Standard system values like fmOpenReadWrite are in SysUtils. }
  fm_APPEND_FLAG  = $20000;
  fm_REWRITE_FLAG = $10000;

  { combined Friendly mode flag values }
  fm_Append          = fmOpenReadWrite or fm_APPEND_FLAG;
  fm_OpenReadShared  = fmOpenRead      or fmShareDenyWrite;
  fm_OpenRewrite     = fmOpenReadWrite or fm_REWRITE_FLAG;
  fm_Truncate        = fmCreate        or fm_REWRITE_FLAG;
  fm_Rewrite         = fmCreate        or fm_REWRITE_FLAG;

  TextStreamReadChunkSize = 8192; // 8k chunk reads.

resourcestring
    RsECannotReadFile = 'Cannot read file %';


type
  ETextStreamException = class(Exception);

{$ifndef UNICODE}
  RawByteString=AnsiString;
{$endif}

  TTextStream = class(TObject)
  private
    FStream: TFileStream; // Tried TJclFileStream also but it was too slow! Do NOT use JCL streams here. -wpostma.
    FFilename: string;
    FStreamBuffer: PAnsiChar;
    FStreamIndex: Integer;
    FStreamSize: Integer;
    FLastReadFlag: Boolean;

    procedure _StreamReadBufInit;
  public
    function ReadLine: RawByteString;   { read a string, one per line, wow. Text files. Cool eh?}

    procedure Append;
    procedure Rewrite;

    procedure Write(const s: RawByteString);        {write a string. wow, eh? }
    procedure WriteLine(const s: RawByteString);    {write string followed by Cr+Lf }

    procedure WriteChar(c: AnsiChar);

    procedure WriteCrLf;
    //procedure Write(const s: string);

    function Eof: Boolean; {is at end of file? }

    { MODE is typically a fm_xxx constant thatimplies a default set of stream mode bits plus some extended bit flags that are specific to this stream type.}
    constructor Create(const FileName: string; Mode: DWORD = fm_OpenReadShared; Rights: Cardinal = 0); reintroduce; virtual;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    function Size: Int64; //override;   // sanity

    { read-only properties at runtime}
    property Filename: string read FFilename;
    property Stream: TFileStream read FStream; { Get at the underlying stream object}
  end;

implementation





// 2 gigabyte file limit workaround:
function GetFileSizeEx(h: HFILE; FileSize: PULargeInteger): BOOL; stdcall;  external Kernel32;

procedure TTextStream.Append; 
begin
  Stream.Seek(0, soFromEnd);
end;

constructor TTextStream.Create(const FileName: string; Mode: DWORD; Rights: Cardinal);
var
  IsAppend: Boolean;
  IsRewrite: Boolean;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FFilename := FileName;

  FLastReadFlag := False;
  IsAppend := (Mode and fm_APPEND_FLAG) <> 0;
  IsRewrite := (Mode and fm_REWRITE_FLAG) <> 0;

  FStream := TFileStream.Create(Filename, {16 lower bits only}Word(Mode), Rights);

  //Stream := FStream; { this makes everything in the base class actually work if we inherited from Easy Stream}

  if IsAppend then
    Self.Append  // seek to the end.
  else
    Stream.Position := 0;

  if IsRewrite then
    Rewrite;

  _StreamReadBufInit;
end;

destructor TTextStream.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(FStream) then
    FStream.Position := 0; // avoid nukage
  FreeAndNil(FStream);
  FreeMem(FStreamBuffer); // Buffered reads for speed.
  inherited Destroy;
end;

function TTextStream.Eof: Boolean;
begin
  if not Assigned(FStream) then
    Result := False
    //Result := True
  else
    Result := FLastReadFlag and (FStreamIndex >= FStreamSize);
    //Result := FStream.Position >= FStream.Size;
end;

{ TTextStream.ReadLine:
  This reads a line of text, normally terminated by carriage return and/or linefeed
  but it is a bit special, and adapted for CSV usage because CR/LF characters
  inside quotes are read as a single line.

  This is a VERY PERFORMANCE CRITICAL function. We loop tightly inside here.
  So there should be as few procedure-calls inside the repeat loop as possible.


}
function TTextStream.ReadLine: RawByteString;
var
  Buf: array of AnsiChar;
  n: Integer;
  QuoteFlag: Boolean;
  LStreamBuffer: PAnsiChar;
  LStreamSize: Integer;
  LStreamIndex: Integer;

  procedure FillStreamBuffer;
  begin
    FStreamSize := Stream.Read(LStreamBuffer[0], TextStreamReadChunkSize);
    LStreamSize := FStreamSize;
    if LStreamSize = 0 then
    begin
      if FStream.Position >= FStream.Size then
        FLastReadFlag := True
      else
        raise ETextStreamException.CreateResFmt(@RsECannotReadFile, [FFilename]);
    end
    else
    if LStreamSize < TextStreamReadChunkSize then
      FLastReadFlag := True;
    FStreamIndex := 0;
    LStreamIndex := 0;
  end;

begin
  { Ignore linefeeds, read until carriage return, strip carriage return, and return it }
  SetLength(Buf, 150);

  n := 0;
  QuoteFlag := False;

  LStreamBuffer := FStreamBuffer;
  LStreamSize := FStreamSize;
  LStreamIndex := FStreamIndex;
  while True do
  begin
    if n >= Length(Buf) then
      SetLength(Buf, n + 100);

    if LStreamIndex >= LStreamSize then
      FillStreamBuffer;

    if LStreamIndex >= LStreamSize then
      Break;

    Buf[n] := LStreamBuffer[LStreamIndex];
    Inc(LStreamIndex);

    case Buf[n] of
      cQuote: {34} // quote
        QuoteFlag := not QuoteFlag;
      cLf: {10} // linefeed
        if not QuoteFlag then
          Break;
      cCR: {13} // carriage return
        begin
          if not QuoteFlag then
          begin
            { If it is a CRLF we must skip the LF. Otherwise the next call to ReadLine
              would return an empty line. }
            if LStreamIndex >= LStreamSize then
              FillStreamBuffer;
            if LStreamBuffer[LStreamIndex] = cLf then
              Inc(LStreamIndex);

            Break;
          end;
        end
    end;
    Inc(n);
  end;
  FStreamIndex := LStreamIndex;

  SetString(Result, PAnsiChar(@Buf[0]), n);
end;

procedure TTextStream.Rewrite;
begin
  if Assigned(FStream) then
    FStream.Size := 0;// truncate!
end;

function TTextStream.Size: Int64; { Get file size }
begin
  if Assigned(FStream) then
    GetFileSizeEx(FStream.Handle, PULargeInteger(@Result)) {int64 Result}
  else
    Result := 0;
end;

{ Look at this. A stream that can handle a string parameter. What will they think of next? }
procedure TTextStream.Write(const s: RawByteString);
begin
  Stream.Write(s[1], Length(s)); {The author of TStreams would like you not to be able to just write Stream.Write(s).  Weird. }
end;

procedure TTextStream.WriteChar(c: AnsiChar);
begin
  Stream.Write(c, SizeOf(AnsiChar));
end;

procedure TTextStream.WriteCrLf;
begin
  WriteChar(#13);
  WriteChar(#10);
end;

procedure TTextStream.WriteLine(const s: RawByteString);
begin
  Write(s);
  WriteCrLf;
end;

procedure TTextStream._StreamReadBufInit;
begin
  if not Assigned(FStreamBuffer) then
  begin
    //FStreamBuffer := AllocMem(TextStreamReadChunkSize);
    GetMem(FStreamBuffer, TextStreamReadChunkSize);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: How does this work without changes on the business code? Which were explicitly excluded?

Comment: I am unable to provide that part of it with this approach.  You can write a true var-args function in C/C++ but you can't with Pascal, and so, you're stuck using WriteLn, which has its own set of drawbacks.  I posted this because others who search question name might not be against changing WriteLn(F,x,y,z) to F.WriteLine(FOrmat('aaa',[x,y,z]))

Comment: I'm not seeing the truth of the C remark. For this kind of stuff array of const would be enough, IF I were to rewrite it. But it changing the exact positioning and floating point formatting  that I want to avoid, since multiple clients have their own hand crafted (and probably horribly buggy) parsers for the format. Or some customers that notices a slightly different rounding algo etc.

Comment: So define rewrite then?  I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: I want to leave my current validated code that is based on stuff like writeln(f,myfloat:10:4,i:4,s:5); alone. Just redirect "f" to something that is not really a TEXT file, but a memorystream, since I now have to store it asynchronously. See other answers. Btw, can I gather from your code that length(rawbytestring) always returns the length in bytes (thus twice*chars when a unicodestring is passed to it?)

Comment: It is purely byte-level and the intention is that if you wanted to add UTF-8 or UTF-16 you would subclass it and change such behaviours in a subclass. FOr example, there is no BOM handling in this class.  Obviously it is completely incompatible with UTF-16 Line Endings (CR/LF) in its current form.

Answer (score 1):

I have just used Warren's TextStreamUnit and it works (thank you Warren), but since I also needed a Handle I have modified the source code to include it. Function IsFileInUse(FileName) used in sample code can be found here: http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2009/qt/is-file-in-use.htm. This combination has helped me to handle all tested situations when multiple clients read often some network file but rarely write to it, without having some server application serializing write requests. Feel free to make any improvements to my modified sample code. Btw, you will probably want to show hour glass cursor during this operation.

Here is the sample code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  MAX_RETRIES_TO_LOCK_FILE = 5;
  TIME_BETWEEN_LOCK_RETRIES = 300; // ms
  FILENAME = 'c:\temp\test.txt';
var
  ts:TTextStream;
  counter: byte;
begin
  try
    for counter := 1 to MAX_RETRIES_TO_LOCK_FILE do
    begin
      if not IsFileInUse(FILENAME) then
      begin
        // ts := TTextStream.Create(FILENAME, fmCreate or fmShareDenyWrite);
        ts := TTextStream.Create(FILENAME, fmOpenReadWrite or fmShareDenyWrite);
        if ts.Handle > 0 then
          Break
        else
          FreeAndNil(ts)
      end
      else
      begin
        Sleep(TIME_BETWEEN_LOCK_RETRIES); // little pause then try again
      end;
    end;
    if ts.Handle > 0 then
      ts.WriteLine('something')
    else
      MessageDlg('Failed to create create or access file, mtError, [mbOK], 0);
  finally
    if Assigned(ts) then
    begin
      FlushFileBuffers(ts.Handle);
      FreeAndNil(ts);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Here is the modified unit:

```
unit TextStreamUnit;
{$M+}


{$R-}

{
  TextStreamUnit

  This code is based on some of the content of the JvCsvDataSet written by Warren Postma, and others,
  licensed under MOZILLA Public License.
}

interface

uses
  Windows,
  Classes,
  SysUtils;


const
  cQuote = #34;
  cLf    = #10;
  cCR    = #13;

 { File stream mode flags used in TTextStream }

  { Significant 16 bits are reserved for standard file stream mode bits. }
  { Standard system values like fmOpenReadWrite are in SysUtils. }
  fm_APPEND_FLAG  = $20000;
  fm_REWRITE_FLAG = $10000;

  { combined Friendly mode flag values }
  fm_Append          = fmOpenReadWrite or fm_APPEND_FLAG;
  fm_OpenReadShared  = fmOpenRead      or fmShareDenyWrite;
  fm_OpenRewrite     = fmOpenReadWrite or fm_REWRITE_FLAG;
  fm_Truncate        = fmCreate        or fm_REWRITE_FLAG;
  fm_Rewrite         = fmCreate        or fm_REWRITE_FLAG;

  TextStreamReadChunkSize = 8192; // 8k chunk reads.

resourcestring
  RsECannotReadFile = 'Cannot read file %';


type
  ETextStreamException = class(Exception);

{$ifndef UNICODE}
  RawByteString=AnsiString;
{$endif}

  TTextStream = class(TObject)
  private
    FStream: TFileStream; // Tried TJclFileStream also but it was too slow! Do NOT use JCL streams here. -wpostma.
    FFilename: string;
    FStreamBuffer: PAnsiChar;
    FStreamIndex: Integer;
    FStreamSize: Integer;
    FLastReadFlag: Boolean;
    FHandle: integer;
    procedure _StreamReadBufInit;
  public
    function ReadLine: RawByteString;   { read a string, one per line, wow. Text files. Cool eh?}
    procedure Append;
    procedure Rewrite;
    procedure Write(const s: RawByteString);        {write a string. wow, eh? }
    procedure WriteLine(const s: RawByteString);    {write string followed by Cr+Lf }
    procedure WriteChar(c: AnsiChar);
    procedure WriteCrLf;
    //procedure Write(const s: string);
    function Eof: Boolean; {is at end of file? }
    { MODE is typically a fm_xxx constant thatimplies a default set of stream mode bits plus some extended bit flags that are specific to this stream type.}
    constructor Create(const FileName: string; Mode: DWORD = fm_OpenReadShared; Rights: Cardinal = 0); reintroduce; virtual;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Size: Int64; //override;   // sanity
    { read-only properties at runtime}
    property Filename: string read FFilename;
    property Handle: integer read FHandle;
    property Stream: TFileStream read FStream; { Get at the underlying stream object}
  end;

implementation


// 2 gigabyte file limit workaround:
function GetFileSizeEx(h: HFILE; FileSize: PULargeInteger): BOOL; stdcall;  external Kernel32;

procedure TTextStream.Append;
begin
  Stream.Seek(0, soFromEnd);
end;

constructor TTextStream.Create(const FileName: string; Mode: DWORD; Rights: Cardinal);
var
  IsAppend: Boolean;
  IsRewrite: Boolean;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FFilename := FileName;

  FLastReadFlag := False;
  IsAppend := (Mode and fm_APPEND_FLAG) <> 0;
  IsRewrite := (Mode and fm_REWRITE_FLAG) <> 0;

  FStream := TFileStream.Create(Filename, {16 lower bits only}Word(Mode), Rights);
  FHandle := FStream.Handle;
  //Stream := FStream; { this makes everything in the base class actually work if we inherited from Easy Stream}

  if IsAppend then
    Self.Append  // seek to the end.
  else
    Stream.Position := 0;

  if IsRewrite then
    Rewrite;

  _StreamReadBufInit;
end;

destructor TTextStream.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(FStream) then
    FStream.Position := 0; // avoid nukage
  FreeAndNil(FStream);
  FreeMem(FStreamBuffer); // Buffered reads for speed.
  inherited Destroy;
end;

function TTextStream.Eof: Boolean;
begin
  if not Assigned(FStream) then
    Result := False
    //Result := True
  else
    Result := FLastReadFlag and (FStreamIndex >= FStreamSize);
    //Result := FStream.Position >= FStream.Size;
end;

{ TTextStream.ReadLine:
  This reads a line of text, normally terminated by carriage return and/or linefeed
  but it is a bit special, and adapted for CSV usage because CR/LF characters
  inside quotes are read as a single line.

  This is a VERY PERFORMANCE CRITICAL function. We loop tightly inside here.
  So there should be as few procedure-calls inside the repeat loop as possible.
}
function TTextStream.ReadLine: RawByteString;
var
  Buf: array of AnsiChar;
  n: Integer;
  QuoteFlag: Boolean;
  LStreamBuffer: PAnsiChar;
  LStreamSize: Integer;
  LStreamIndex: Integer;

  procedure FillStreamBuffer;
  begin
    FStreamSize := Stream.Read(LStreamBuffer[0], TextStreamReadChunkSize);
    LStreamSize := FStreamSize;
    if LStreamSize = 0 then
    begin
      if FStream.Position >= FStream.Size then
        FLastReadFlag := True
      else
        raise ETextStreamException.CreateResFmt(@RsECannotReadFile, [FFilename]);
    end
    else
    if LStreamSize < TextStreamReadChunkSize then
      FLastReadFlag := True;
    FStreamIndex := 0;
    LStreamIndex := 0;
  end;

begin
  { Ignore linefeeds, read until carriage return, strip carriage return, and return it }
  SetLength(Buf, 150);

  n := 0;
  QuoteFlag := False;

  LStreamBuffer := FStreamBuffer;
  LStreamSize := FStreamSize;
  LStreamIndex := FStreamIndex;
  while True do
  begin
    if n >= Length(Buf) then
      SetLength(Buf, n + 100);

    if LStreamIndex >= LStreamSize then
      FillStreamBuffer;

    if LStreamIndex >= LStreamSize then
      Break;

    Buf[n] := LStreamBuffer[LStreamIndex];
    Inc(LStreamIndex);

    case Buf[n] of
      cQuote: {34} // quote
        QuoteFlag := not QuoteFlag;
      cLf: {10} // linefeed
        if not QuoteFlag then
          Break;
      cCR: {13} // carriage return
        begin
          if not QuoteFlag then
          begin
            { If it is a CRLF we must skip the LF. Otherwise the next call to ReadLine
              would return an empty line. }
            if LStreamIndex >= LStreamSize then
              FillStreamBuffer;
            if LStreamBuffer[LStreamIndex] = cLf then
              Inc(LStreamIndex);
            Break;
          end;
        end
    end;
    Inc(n);
  end;
  FStreamIndex := LStreamIndex;

  SetString(Result, PAnsiChar(@Buf[0]), n);
end;

procedure TTextStream.Rewrite;
begin
  if Assigned(FStream) then
    FStream.Size := 0;// truncate!
end;

function TTextStream.Size: Int64; { Get file size }
begin
  if Assigned(FStream) then
    GetFileSizeEx(FStream.Handle, PULargeInteger(@Result)) {int64 Result}
  else
    Result := 0;
end;

{ Look at this. A stream that can handle a string parameter. What will they think of next? }
procedure TTextStream.Write(const s: RawByteString);
begin
  Stream.Write(s[1], Length(s)); {The author of TStreams would like you not to be able to just write Stream.Write(s).  Weird. }
end;

procedure TTextStream.WriteChar(c: AnsiChar);
begin
  Stream.Write(c, SizeOf(AnsiChar));
end;

procedure TTextStream.WriteCrLf;
begin
  WriteChar(#13);
  WriteChar(#10);
end;

procedure TTextStream.WriteLine(const s: RawByteString);
begin
  Write(s);
  WriteCrLf;
end;

procedure TTextStream._StreamReadBufInit;
begin
  if not Assigned(FStreamBuffer) then
  begin
    //FStreamBuffer := AllocMem(TextStreamReadChunkSize);
    GetMem(FStreamBuffer, TextStreamReadChunkSize);
  end;
end;

end.
```